# How to get the objectId for the Debugger.setBreakpointOnFunctionCall command in a C++ project using V8 engine?

Tags: javascript, embedded-v8, chrome-debugging

I am using v8 engine inspctor to debug javascript in my own c++ project ,  I sent the debug command Debugger.setBreakpointOnFunctionCall to v8 engine to set a breakpoint before call a function ( function Action() ) ,  the command is a JSON  string ,  the content of the command is as follows :

"{"id":11,"method":"Debugger.setBreakpointOnFunctionCall","params":{"objectId":"-6103739057120817852.1.11" }}"

The objectId in the JSON string refer to the function to be called. My problem is how can I get the objectId before use it in my own c++ project ? Can i get the objectId by v8 engine interface in my code or I must send a request JSON command to v8 engine to get the objectId?

Where can I get some samples of how to use the newest v8 engine inspctor debug command ?

Comment: the chatgpt4's answer is sending a Runtime.evaluate debug command to get the objectId of the function. I tried to send a JSON string:

"{\"id\":11,\"method\":\"Runtime.evaluate\",\"params\":{\"expression\":\"vuser_init\"}}"

but I received the result:

"{\"id\":11,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"Cannot find context with specified id\"}}"

what's wrong with the Runtime.evaluate command?  I guess the default context goes wrong.